# Duplicate sheet with format in Excel

Tags: r, excel, xlsx

Hi this question is a driven by the curiosity to use the `xlsx` package more extensively when exporting data from R to Excel. I simply would like to create an exact copy of an existing sheet including all formats. I can manage to copy the values, but I cannot copy the styles. I would also be curious if there is another alternative to directly duplicate a sheet.

Unfortunately, I do not have a data source file, so here is a picture of my MWE data source. Is it even possible to just extract the styles from the existing table and paste them onto the copy?

Please note that I cannot use the `openxlsx` package since I cannot install `rtools` on my computer

[image]

```
library(xlsx)
files<-"Test.xlsx"
wb<-xlsx::loadWorkbook(files)
createSheet(wb, sheetName = "copy")
# get values and styles from original sheet
sheets <- getSheets(wb)
rows <- getRows(sheets[[1]])  # get rows
cells <- getCells(rows)  
values<-lapply(cells, getCellValue)
styles<-lapply(cells, getCellStyle)
#Create new rows and cells
rows.new <- createRow(sheets[[4]],1:length(rows))  # get rows
cells.new <- createCell(rows.new,1:2)  
#set cell values, but not working for styles
mapply(setCellValue,cells.new,matrix(unlist(values), nrow=3, ncol=2,byrow=TRUE))
mapply(setCellStyle,cells.new,matrix(unlist(styles), nrow=3, ncol=2,byrow=TRUE))
#save workbook
saveWorkbook(wb, file=files)
```

Comment: Should be possible to extract using *openxlsx*, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49287123) to extract comments, if you load the file using `openxlsx::loadWorkbook`, then check the structure to find where formatting is stored, then extract.

Comment: You may also want to have a look at the XLConnect package. It has a method cloneSheet that "Clones (copies) a worksheet in a workbook." https://rdrr.io/cran/XLConnect/man/cloneSheet-methods.html

Comment: Thanks for the Feedback, I added the restriction that I cannot use `openxls`, Ill look into `XLconncet`, which I already use sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy excel sheets with the RDCOMClient R package. Here is an example :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
path_Excel_File_Output <- "D:\\output.xlsx"
path_Excel_File1 <- "D:\\file1.xlsx"
path_Excel_File2 <- "D:\\file2.xlsx"

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlWbk1 <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File1)
xlWbk2 <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File2)

# Copy one sheet after another ... 
xlWbk1$Worksheets(1)$Copy(after = xlWbk2$Worksheets(1))
xlWbk2$SaveAs(path_Excel_File_Output)
xlWbk1$Close()
xlWbk2$Close()
xlApp$Quit()
```